# Staking deactivating

Tags: staking, sol

[image: **staking Deactivating **]

I have deactivated my staking of sol 2 days ago but it is still showing deactivating. I'm new to Phantom so I Don't know how much time will will take to compete the Process. If anyone knows then Please let me know. Thank YOU so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you deactivate stake, it takes until the start of the next epoch for it to be deactivated.

Epochs usually last a little over 2 days. The next epoch will finalize in less than 4 hours, and that's when your stake will be available for withdrawal.